# Error in saving an excel file modified by pandas

Tags: python, excel

I'm trying to replace some values from a cell in Excel by others in only one column, example:

```
p1  
____________________
dec.2011-Actualidad
mar.2008-Present
ene.2010-Actualidad
```

I want to translate everything to English so I have to replace 'Actualidad' by 'Present', and 'ene.' by 'Jan.' and so on, therefore I used the following command:

```
df=pd.read_excel(‘Excel1.xlsx')
df['p1'].replace('ene.', value='jan.',regex=True)
df.to_excel(r'/Users/User1/test1.xlsx')
```

That command only allowed me to change one value at a time and once I save the file the replacements are not changed.

In order to change more values I tried:

```
df['p1'].replace({'dic.', value='dec.'}, {'ene.', value='jan.’}, regex=True)
```

But it didn't work.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `replace` method isn't inplace, so you need to do one of two possibilities:

```
df['p1'].replace('ene.', value='jan.',regex=True, inplace=True)
```

or

```
df['p1'] = df['p1'].replace('ene.', value='jan.',regex=True)
```